Dynamic Time Warping (DTW) algorithm with different time lengths ... should i truncate time series?
I have $\{Y\}_t$ time series, and want to find the closest time series from $N$ different series, i.e., $\{X^{1}\}_{t}, \{X^{2}\}_{t}, ..., \{X^{N}\}_{t}$, by applying DTW algorithm. Each of $N$ series has different lengths, i.e., $Y$ has 100 observations, but some of $Xs$ could have 1,000 and even more. As the length varies, should I cut $\{X^{1}\}_{t}, \{X^{2}\}_{t}, ..., \{X^{N}\}_{t}$ to make of the same length as $\{Y\}_t$? If no, how to manage this within R?

No, if you want to use DTW, then you should not "cut" any series. The reason for this is that DTW can compare series of different lengths, which is one of the main strengths of DTW.
In R, you can use the DTW package. For example dtw::dtw(1:3,1:1000) computes the DTW alignment and the DTW distance between the sequences $1,2,3$ and $1,2,...,999,1000$. You can retrieve the DTW distance using
result <- dtw::dtw(X,Y)
result$distance

Note that the DTW distance is generally larger for longer sequences. A simple heuristic to address this problem is to divide the resulting distance by the length of the longer sequence, e.g., with result$distance / max(c(length(X),length(Y)))
Note though that this does not always solve the problem. For more details, please refer to the specific answers regarding the normalization of DTW: Answer by Laurent Duval

Thank you! The thing is if we have define $X={1,2,3}$ and $Y={1,2,3}$, then DTW is 0. On the other hand, if we have $X={1,2,3}$ and $Y={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,....,1000}$, then DTW is 497503 (I computed in R). Does this make sense? The algorithm made the distance huge because of missing values.

The value you computed is correct. DTW cannot handle linear trends. If 1:3 and 1:1000 should have the same distance, then you would need to detrend the sequences, e.g., with pracma::detrend(). Note that DTW work correctly in general, e.g. dtw::dtw(rep(0,3),rep(0,1000)) yields distance 0.

I did another exercise. I generated $X$ and $Y$ from $N(0,1)$ distribution, 10 observations for each series. DTW is 5.8. Then, I generated for $X$ 1,000 observations from the same distribution, while keeping $Y$ the same (i.e., 10 observations from standard normal distribution). DTW is 772.6. Dramatic change due to difference in lengths of time series. Do you think that this again make any sense? DTW algorithm in actuality can deal with comparison between two unequal length time series, but the question is whether it makes a reasonable comparison.

@Sane You would expect the distance to get larger, because you are comparing more values, with more "random errors". e.g. if you compare $X$ and $Y$ drawn from $N(0,1)$ and both have length $1000$, then you also get a DTW distance around 800. You can somewhat mitigate this effect by dividing the DTW distance by the length of the longer sequence

I see, thank you. But is there any cost to pay for truncating/cutting? Do I get any value just keeping them as they are?

If you truncate the sequence, you might be removing the part that matters. For example, $X={1,2,3}, Y={0,0,0,0,1,2,3}$. DTW(X,Y) has distance 4, but if you truncate Y to the first three values $Y'={0,0,0}$, then DTW(X,Y') has distance 8. Similar problems can occur if you truncate the longer sequence to the last, or middle, or other values

Yes, makes sense, thank you. As I am comparing $X$ with many other alternative series (to find the "closest" one) which have different lengths, can I just divided by the length of the longest series (as you suggested) to make DTW values from different pairs comparable?

Yes, this is one way of doing it. I will edit the answer to reflect on our discussion

Would be great, thank you !

One more question please ... do you know how DTW algorithm equalize time series in terms of length? Does it just put 0 values instead of missing values?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I have a new question about DTW in here. Please have a look. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/644200/error-in-dynamic-time-warping-dtw-algorithm

The paper below lists all options for this problem
Chang Wei Tan, François Petitjean, Eamonn J. Keogh, Geoffrey I. Webb:
Time series classification for varying length series. CoRR abs/1910.04341 (2019)

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
