Error in Dynamic Time Warping (DTW) algorithm
I am applying Dynamic Time Warping algorithm to measure the distance between 2 time series, but get the following error in R: Error in dtw(series_test, series_train, window.type = "sakoechiba", window.size = 5) : No warping path exists that is allowed by costraints. I have tried to manipulate my command by changing arguments, but doesn't work. What could be the source of this issue, and how solve in R? Thank you!
